# Wine installation problem with ubuntu 17.10 64bit

Tags: wine, dpkg, 64-bit

So, I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my 64 bit PC. After that I went to install chromium, spotify and other daily things I use on my PC. But then I needed to install some sort of program to be able to play **Paladins** on it.
 I went to google it and found out that I need to use **Wine**. Fine. I went to their website and did everything I was asked. Here's what I did:

1. I went to the "Download" page.
2. I clicked on "Ubuntu - WineHQ binary packages for Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, and 17.10"
3. "If your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already)". I also did that too. When I ran the code: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` I get this: `dpkg: error: unknown option --add-arhitecture`
4. I ignored it (Maybe I was a fool for doing that), and moved on. I did the rest of the things that returned "OK" but then I run this code: `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable` and I get this error: `E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable`

Now, I don't know if it is from my Ubuntu installation as I took it from their website so I suppose it is a "clean" installation. I used PowerISO tools to create a bootable USB. Everything went perfect on the installation, so I don't think it is from the OS itself. Thank you if you at least tried to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad 3** - error print `dpkg: error: unknown option --add-arhitecture` suggests that maybe a typo is an issue - "arhitecture" instead of "architecture" ?

**Ad 4** - did you add repositories according to [WineHQ Manual](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) ?

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

then`sudo apt-get update`

then `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Comment: Yeah, I did a mistake there with "arhitecture" as I wasn't paying attention. Now it is all back to normal only one thing. Wine does not show up in the "Show Applications" menu so I can't use it. Do I have to reboot my PC? Also, thanks for the response.

Comment: Wine doesn't have itself any graphical interface except winecfg command running GUI configuration tool. That is why you can't see wine in "Show Applications". Just run from terminal "wine app.exe". Considering graphical interface and gaming on linux possibly you can be interested in PlayonLinux https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html . Interesting could be also https://appdb.winehq.org to check for useful tips&tricks to run some software on Wine

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about playonlinux. I did use it, but when I installed "InstallPaladins.exe" it does not show in the programs list at all. I will just try wine. 
EDIT: Just tried wine and it give me this error `wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\app.exe"`

Comment: Ah, I should have given wine yourapp.exe :) Just example, therefore it does not exist but propably means it does work eventually :)

Comment: God, I wish I wasn't so new to linux. Now it returns `wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\paladins.exe` or if I needed to point the installer it returns `wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\installpaladins.exe`

Comment: You should try with absolute path aka wine /home/user/game.exe or you can go to the directory with game cd /home/user then wine game.exe. Unless you are in exe directory it will always look for exe in system32 which is default wine foldet